# Google Maps API v3. How to hide markers on map depending on day & time?

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

Ok, I have a project map that im working on that pulls data from mysql. in my DB I have a column called "weekends" with a value of "0 or 1" The value of "1" will mean to show the marker no matter of the day or time of the week.

For all other markers i need them to hide for example; from Friday 9 pm to Sunday 9pm. Unless they have the value of "1" in the weekend column, then they would show.

Can anyone help me construct this java script function? Any help will be much appreciated.

here is  my code:

```
//Icon Selection
    var customIcons = {
      Full: {
        icon: 'red.png'

      },
      Partial: {
        icon: 'blue.png',

      }

    };


function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.075287, -80.309029),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var Udf_DSCategory = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSCategory");
      var Description = markers[i].getAttribute("Description");
      var Udf_DSLimitsTo = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSLimitsTo");
      var Udf_DSType = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSType");
      var Udf_DSPIONotes = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSPIONotes");
      var Udf_DSApprovedBy = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSApprovedBy");
    var Udf_DSLimitsOfClosure = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSLimitsOfClosure");
    var ProjectName = markers[i].getAttribute("ProjectName");
    var Udf_DSDateClosureFrom = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSDateClosureFrom");   
    var Udf_DSDateClosureTo = markers[i].getAttribute("Udf_DSDateClosureTo");
    var weekend = markers[i].getAttribute("weekend");               
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("UserText1")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("BulletinID")));

      var html = 

     "<b> Project Name: </b> " + ProjectName +  "<br/>" +"<b> Category: </b> " + Udf_DSCategory + " <br/>" + "<b> Closure Type: </b>" + Udf_DSType + "  <br/> <b> Date From: </b> " + Udf_DSDateClosureFrom + " <b>to</b> " + Udf_DSDateClosureTo + " <br/>" + "<b> Road: </b>" + Description + "<br/>" + "<b> Closure Notes: </b>" + Udf_DSPIONotes + "<br/>" + "<b> Closure Approved by: </b>" + Udf_DSApprovedBy ;


      var icon = customIcons[Udf_DSType] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow,

        }); 



      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }
  });


}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}


function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: A dataBase usually knows about date and time, why don't you fetch only the markers you need from the DB?

Comment: how would i query that? its a mysql DB.

Comment: I'd like to see this question answered, as there are use cases where you want to toggle data display w/o going to the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the comment, it would be the best to fetch only the needed markers from the DB.

The query may look like this(there may be a lot of other ways)

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` 
   WHERE( weekends=1 
            OR
          WEEKDAY(NOW())<4 
            OR 
          (WEEKDAY(NOW())=4 AND HOUR(NOW())<18)
            OR 
          (WEEKDAY(NOW())=6 AND HOUR(NOW())>17)
        )
```

Comment: so if I modify the query, I would not have to modify the javascript, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, the query will only return rows where weekends is set to 1 or all rows when the current server-time is not within the specified range(friday 9pm-sunday 9pm)

Comment: Worked like a charm, with a few mods. Thanks!